# Do all right triangles have the same angles?

Tags: triangles

I'm trying to find the complementary angles in a right rectangle and I've thought in these two triangles:

[image]

Do **A** and **B** have the same angles?

At first, I thought so. But now, I'm not sure. I think the angles value depend on the length of segments **c**, **d**, **e** and **f**.

Comment: No, the other angles can have every value as long as they sum to $90$ degrees and are strictly between $0$ and $90$ degrees.

Comment: "I think the angles value depend on the length of segments c, d, e and f." You thought correct.

Comment: @hellofriends You mean all right triangles would have this property , since the question assumes right triangles.

Comment: @Peter drawing the heights of a random triangle you would get either that the triangle is equilateral or rectangle and isosceles I think

Comment: Do you already have learned how the sine , the cosine and the tangens of the angles of a right triangle can be expressed by two of the sides ?

Comment: @Peter No, I don't.

Comment: Simple test: in the triangle A, make the top vertex move along the vertical: the triangle still has a right angle, what about the other two, are they constant?

Comment: See also [the law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) and [the law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).